# Should vs Will?

Tags: meaning

What is the difference, if any, between the following:

> 1. the building materials should be stored on pallets
> 2. the building materials will be stored on pallets

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that really makes it clear now.

Answer (score 3):

There is an important difference.  "Should" implies necessity or expression of an opinion.  The building materials need to be stored there at some point in the future and there may be bad consequences if they are not.

"Will" implies that in the future the building materials are going to be stored there as part of a plan.

Please see the [following as a reference](https://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/will-would-shall-should), which I quote below

In this case, "Should" here is being used

> to give an opinion, to make a suggestion, express a preference or an idea.

and "Will" here is being used

> to show the future

Comment: I would say that "should" is milder than necessity. To me it implies a recommendation: it is not essential to store them on pallets but it would be better if you did. Standards documents generally use "shall" for mandatory requirements to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @JamesRandom Neither *should* nor *will* implies necessity: *should* refers to what ought to be done (in the speaker's opinion), and *will* refers to what is required to be done - but neither relates specifically to *necessity*.

Comment: @JamesRandom There is a third version, which really does imply necessity or compulsion. It is "**Building materials _must_ be stored on pallets**". This is either a practical necessity in that non-compliance will result in damage of some sort or a legal or contractural obligation possibly resulting in someone losing their job in the event of non-compliance.

Comment: @JamesRandom I tried to edit my explanation as to incorporate both ideas because "Should" could have multiple meanings in the context.